# построить распределение рандомных чисел

Tags: c++, visual-c++, статистика

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int mas[11] = { 0 }; //заполняем массив нулями
    int i = 0, l = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) //повторение цикла 1000 раз
    {
        i = rand() % 10; //создаем случайное число от 0 до 10
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++, l++)   // 10 повторений цикла сравнения, при каждом повторе переходим на следующую область k=0(0<i<1) k=1(1<i<2) ... k=9(9<i<10)
            if (i < 0 + l && i < l + 1) // проверяем попадает ли i в область
                mas[k]++; //увеличиваем позицию массива соответствующую номеру области на 1 
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) //выводим все элементы массива в столбец
        cout << mas[n] << endl;
}
```

что-бы на выходе получить следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя сумма всех выведенных чисел должна быть равна 1000.

Смотрели другом, ничего не нашли. Прошу помощи, заранее благодарю

Comment: `i < 0 + l && i < l + 1` ???

Comment: *//создаем случайное число от 0 до 10* Вы хотели сказать, до 9?

Comment: Сравнение, i>l И i<l+1. Была ошибка, но не основная, если заменить "<" на ">" в выводе столбец из десяти нулей

Comment: "//создаем случайное число от 0 до 10 Вы хотели сказать, до 9?" Имел ввиду строгий интервал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все точно так же, как у Harry, и для квадратов:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int mas[11] = { 0 };
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
    {
        double p = double(rand())/RAND_MAX;
        p *= p;

        mas[int(p*10)]++;
    }
    for (int d = 0; d < 11; d++)
        cout << mas[d] << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас "зачем просто, если можно сложно"...

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int mas[11] = { 0 };           //заполняем массив нулями
    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) //повторение цикла 1000 раз
        mas[rand() % 11]++;        //создаем случайное число от 0 до 10
    for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++)  //выводим все элементы массива в столбец
        cout << mas[n] << endl;
}
```

И, кстати, `main()` возвращает `int`, а не `void`.

Comment: упростил задачу, изначально был вопрос о не целых числах ```#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void main()
{

 double i, p = 0.0, ni = 0, t, l = 0.0;
 srand(time(0));
 int mas[11] = { 0 };
 for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
 {
  double p = rand();
  t = p / 32767.0;
  i = pow(t, 2);
  cout << t<< setw(15)<< i<< endl;
  for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++, l += 0.1)
  {
   if (i > l)
    mas[k]++;
   if (i < 0.1 + l)
    mas[k]++;

  }

 }
 for (int d = 0; d < 11; d++)
  cout << mas[d] << endl;

} ``` Почему так криво вставилось?